# Catch an Exception from an async Event Handler

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a "background job" class that runs a job asynchronously and raises an event whenever progress is made. If the event handler for this event raises an exception, it is never caught by the calling method.

If I switch my event handler to be non-async. the problem goes away. But then I'd have to make all async calls from the event handler into blocking calls, and I'd rather not have to do that!

Is there any way to catch an exception raised from an async event handler?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncEventHandlingIssue
{
    public class BackgroundJob
    {
        public int Progress { get; private set; }
        public event EventHandler ProgressUpdated;
        public async Task Start()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Progress++;
                ProgressUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var job = new BackgroundJob();
            job.ProgressUpdated += Job_ProgressUpdated;
            try
            {
                await job.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The job failed with an error: {ex}");
            }
        }

        private static async void Job_ProgressUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var job = (BackgroundJob)sender;
            await Task.Delay(100); // just an example - my real code needs to call async methods.
            Console.WriteLine($"The Job is at {job.Progress}%.");
            if (job.Progress == 5)
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine("Reached the end of the program.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'be been led to ask the wrong question. Progress reports are an implementation of the Observer pattern. You should never *need* to catch a handler exception in an event source; the fact that you need to indicates that you're not using the Observer pattern but rather something else. E.g., Template Method is often mis-implemented using events.

Comment: @StephenCleary That's a very good point. I am indeed guilty of what you're suggesting and I'm pretty sure I can rewrite using the tips I got from JSteward below to avoid this problem. Now with that out of the way, just for personal curiosity, isn't it always _possible_ that an exception could be thrown from event handling code? And if exceptions from an async void event handler can never be caught, shouldn't they always be wrapped in a blanket try/catch to avoid crashing an application? Thanks!

Comment: `async void` emulates (top-level) UI event handlers; when a UI event raises an exception, it goes straight to the message loop, so `async void` methods emulate that behavior by raising the exception directly on a `SynchronizationContext`. So, if you need a try/catch in your UI event handler, then you will need one in your `async void` method. There are some workarounds that allow catching the exceptions (like having `Task`-returning events), but a redesign is the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `async void` method will throw it's exceptions on its captured context your `try catch` should be within the `async` method. Additionally what your doing sounds an awful lot like the old `BackgroundWorker`, don't reinvent the wheel and there is already much better options to run `async` jobs that report progress. Have look [here](http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress) for `async` progress updates. Here's a simple example that takes advantage of `async await` and the `async` progress updates:

```
public class BackgroundJob {

    public async Task Start(IProgress<int> progress) {            
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            progress.Report(i);
            //the method executing the job should determine something is wrong
            if (i == 5)
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }
}

public class Program {
    static async Task MainAsync() {
        var job = new BackgroundJob();
        var progress = new Progress<int>(Job_ProgressUpdated);
        try {
            await job.Start(progress);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //now your exception is caught
            Console.WriteLine($"The job failed with an error: {ex}");
        }
    }

    private static async void Job_ProgressUpdated(int progress)  {
        await Task.Delay(100); // just an example - my real code needs to call async methods.
        Console.WriteLine($"The Job is at {progress}%.");
        //***
        //a progress update should not determine if something went wrong
        //***
        //if (progress == 5)
        //throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Reached the end of the program.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You need to consider that throwing an exception from the progress updated event handler, or any `async` event  handler, is not necessarily going to kill your job. You could however cancel the job from the event handler and catch the `OperationCanceledException` like so:

```
public class BackgroundJob {
    public int Progress { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler ProgressUpdated;
    public async Task Start(CancellationToken token) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Progress++;
            ProgressUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class Program {        

    private static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource()

    static async Task MainAsync() {
        var job = new BackgroundJob();
        job.ProgressUpdated += Job_ProgressUpdated;
        try {
            await job.Start(cts.Token);
        } catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine($"The job failed with an error: {ex}");
        }
    }

    private static async void Job_ProgressUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var job = (BackgroundJob)sender;
        await Task.Delay(100); // just an example - my real code needs to call async methods.
        Console.WriteLine($"The Job is at {job.Progress}%.");
        if (job.Progress == 5)
            cts.Cancel();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Reached the end of the program.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eventhandlers will not swallow exceptions - even with `async void` they will throw exceptions

Comment: @Fabio thanks for that, getting ahead of myself this morning.

Comment: @JSteward What I'm really asking with my code sample is how to handle an exception thrown from an async void event handler. Assuming any non-trivial event handler that _might_ raise something, should all async void event handlers be wrapped in a blanket try... catch?

I will check out the TAP link that you provided. Thanks!

Comment: @James You can catch the exception within the event handler, that obviously doesn't help but if it's the job you want to kill with the exception you'll need to cancel the job. Combine both the proper `async` progress updates and the cancellation and you'll have a well behaved process. On another note if you have many jobs to process check out [TPL Dataflow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to answer to your comment, as your question is mostly covered already.

> And if exceptions from an async void event handler can never be caught, shouldn't they always be wrapped in a blanket try/catch to avoid crashing an application?

Whenever an exception is thrown in an `async void` method, it is posted to the current synchronization context. Most of the time, it results in crashing the application. That's why, yes, `async void` methods should catch the exception whenever this make sense.

That said, there is a hackish way to catch an exception from outside an `async void` method: building a custom synchronization context to intercept the exception.

```
public static void Test()
{
    throw new Exception("Synchronous");
}

public static async void TestAsync()
{
    await Task.Yield();

    throw new Exception("Asynchronous");
}

public class EventSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (state is ExceptionDispatchInfo
            && d.Target.GetType().ReflectedType.FullName == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore")
        {
            // Caught an exception
            var exceptionInfo = (ExceptionDispatchInfo)state;
            Console.WriteLine("Caught asynchronous exception: " + exceptionInfo.SourceException);

            return;
        }

        base.Post(d, state);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeEvent += TestAsync;
    SomeEvent += Test;

    var previousSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    try
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new EventSynchronizationContext());

        SomeEvent();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught synchronous exception: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(previousSynchronizationContext);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm saying this again: I'm merely posting that for the curious minds. This rely on undocumented internal mechanics that could break at any update of the framework, and shouldn't be used in actual production code.